# Is it possible to define a c++ wrapper function for a macro with variadic parameters?

Tags: c++, windows, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I'd like to come up with a c++ wrapper function that fully wraps the [TraceLoggingWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn904617(v=vs.85).aspx) macro. `TraceLoggingWrite` is a macro with variadic parameters. I attempted the following code snippet, but it would encounter compilation errors because it seems like the syntax requires the wrapped function to accept a va_list parameter. If so, is there another way to accomplish this?

```
void WrapperFunction(String Name, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, Name);
    TraceLoggingWrite(gProvider,
                      Name,
                      TraceLoggingInt32(32, "Test"),
                      args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template<typename... Ts>
void WrapperFunction(String Name, Ts... args)
{
    TraceLoggingWrite(gProvider,
        Name,
        TraceLoggingInt32(32, "Test"),
        args...);
}
```

However because `TraceLoggingWrite` is a variadic ***macro***, there might be cases where parameter packs do not work. An alternative would be to create another macro, also variadic, something like this:

```
#define WrapperMacro(eventName, ...) TraceLoggingWrite(gProvider, eventName, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: forwarding reference with `std::forward` can even be used.